# Filter clause in aggregate window not discarding rows as expected

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions, postgresql-9.4

I expect the filter clause to discard rows before passing the rows to the window function. From [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS):

> If FILTER is specified, then only the input rows for which the filter_clause evaluates to true are fed to the window function; other rows are discarded. Only window functions that are aggregates accept a FILTER clause.

However, the following test seems to contradict this:

```
create table test_1 as
select generate_series(1,10) as num;    

select
  *,
  sum(num) over last_2,
  sum(num) filter (where  num % 2 = 0) over last_2
from test_1
window
    last_2 as (order by num rows 1 preceding)
;
```

This returns:

```
 num | sum |  sum   
-----+-----+--------
   1 |   1 | [null]
   2 |   3 |      2
   3 |   5 |      2
   4 |   7 |      4
   5 |   9 |      4
   6 |  11 |      6
   7 |  13 |      6
   8 |  15 |      8
   9 |  17 |      8
  10 |  19 |     10
(10 rows)
```

Take the fourth row as an example. Here the aggregate function should receive the last two even rows (i.e. 2 and 4). So I would expect this sum to be 6.

What am I misunderstanding?

Note: This is a contrived example which distils the problem that I am actually struggling with. There are obviously better ways to find the moving sum of even numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The over clause has precedence over the filter clause. So you take last_2 (i.e. the current row and the previous to it) and from these you filter, which gets you only one row (the even one).

What you are looking for instead is this:

```
sum(case when num % 2 = 0 then num else 0 end) over last_2
```

Comment: That makes sense. How should I do what I am actually trying to do?

Comment: Thanks! What if the aggregate function was AVG(), which will depend on the number of rows?

Comment: Then use `sum(case when num % 2 = 0 then num end) over last_2 / count(case when num % 2 = 0 then num end) over last_2` instead. Or wait, isn't `avg` already ignoring nulls? Then even `avg(case when num % 2 = 0 then num end) over last_2` should do.